# Alterando label e cor das entradas de um pie Chart - Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

Tenho o seguinte código:

public class PontuacaoUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
PieChart graficoUser;
int pontosCor, pontosNumero, pontosObjeto;

FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseAuth auth;
DatabaseReference databaseRef, userDB;

ArrayList<PieEntry> entries;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pontuacao_user);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    userDB = databaseRef.child(user.getUid());

    graficoUser = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.graficoUser);

    userDB.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

            Log.v("map", map+"");

            String username = map.get("username");
            String password = map.get("password");
            String email = map.get("email");
            String pontuacaoObjeto = map.get("pontuacaoObjeto");
            String pontuacaoCor = map.get("pontuacaoCor");
            String pontuacaoNumero = map.get("pontuacaoNumero");

            pontosObjeto = Integer.valueOf(pontuacaoObjeto);
            pontosNumero = Integer.valueOf(pontuacaoNumero);
            pontosCor = Integer.valueOf(pontuacaoCor);

            Log.v("nome: ",email+"");

            entries = new ArrayList<>();
            entries.add(new PieEntry(pontosCor, "cor"));
            entries.add(new PieEntry(pontosNumero, "numero"));
            entries.add(new PieEntry(pontosObjeto, "objeto"));

            PieDataSet dataset = new PieDataSet(entries, "pontuações");

            ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
            labels.add("pontuação da cor");
            labels.add("pontuação do numero");
            labels.add("pontuação do objeto");


            dataset.setLabel(labels.toString());

            PieData data = new PieData(dataset);

            PieChart chart = new PieChart(getApplicationContext());
            setContentView(chart);
            chart.setData(data);
            chart.setContentDescription("pontuações");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Não estou encontrando bons tutoriais na internet que possam me ajudar a alterar cor das entradas e labels.
Ajuda por favor?

este é o efeito atual: 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu trabalhei ainda ontem com essa `lib`, e realmente é meio complicada.

Mas lá vai:

**Adicionar label:**

Para adicionar a label de cada parte do gráfico, voce deve instanciar seu `PieEntry` com *Valor* (float) e *Label*. Por exemplo:

`entries.add(new PieEntry(num, "Custo"));`

**Alterar cores**

Pelo que pesquisei ontem, há varias formas de alterar as cores do gráfico.  Tu pode dar uma olhada na documentaçao deles [aqui](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Colors)

ou pode seguir o que eu fiz, que foi:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.LIBERTY_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    for (int c : ColorTemplate.PASTEL_COLORS)
        colors.add(c);

    colors.add(ColorTemplate.getHoloBlue());

    dataset.setColors(colors);
```

Voce pode também dar uma olhada no [meu projeto](https://github.com/luangs7/ChartProject/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/luan2/chartproject/MainActivity.java), onde adicionei outras questoes pra PieChart. Nao ta completo mas vai te ajudar bastante.

Comment: opa! funcionou :D mas como eu altero a cor dos labels?

Comment: Tipo aqui: 

entries = new ArrayList<>();
                entries.add(new PieEntry(pontosCor, "cor"));
                entries.add(new PieEntry(pontosNumero, "numero"));
                entries.add(new PieEntry(pontosObjeto, "objeto"));

o texto exibido de cada label, logo abaixo do valor, está branco. queria altera-lo assim como o tamanho. tem ideia?

Comment: Descobri ja, olhando o codigo do seu projeto! huauha. mt obg !!!